# jq, variables, select and numbers?

Tags: json, jq

It seems that jq's "select", when used with variables, only works for text strings, but not for numbers.
How do I use jq so that I can select no matter if the value is a number or not?

```
$ cat test.json
[
  {
    "id": "some-text",
    "output": "jq select works!"
  },
  {
    "id": 123,
    "output": "jq select doesn't work :("
  }
]
```

- Let's try to select "output" where "id" is "some-text" - it works:

```
$ ID="some-text"
$ cat test.json | jq -r --arg ID "$ID" '.[] | select(.id==$ID) | .output'
jq select works!
$
```

- Let's try to select "output" where "id" is "123" - it doesn't work:

```
$ ID="123"
$ cat test.json | jq -r --arg ID "$ID" '.[] | select(.id==$ID) | .output'
$
```

- Interestingly, "select" does work if I don't pass the variable via --arg:

```
$ cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | select(.id==123) | .output'
jq select doesn't work :(
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't make `ID="123"` a string, just use an integer: `ID=123`

Comment: Hmm, how exactly do I do it? This comes up with nothing:

ID=123 ; cat test.json | jq -r --arg ID $ID '.[] | select(.id==$ID) | .output'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`--argjson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) instead off `-arg` to let JQ handle it as a number:

```sh
➜  ID="123"
➜  cat test.json | jq -r --argjson ID "$ID" '.[] | select(.id==$ID) | .output'
jq select doesn't work :(
➜
```

---

You could also use [`tostring`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to convert the ID to a string so you can keep the existing format;

```
➜  ID="123"
➜  cat test.json | jq -r --arg ID "$ID" '.[] | select(.id|tostring==$ID) | .output'
jq select doesn't work :(
➜ 
➜  ID="some-text"
➜  cat test.json | jq -r --arg ID "$ID" '.[] | select(.id|tostring==$ID) | .output'
jq select works!
➜
```